# Release an Android app only for smartphones with high density and large screen size

Tags: android, android-manifest

How do I restrict my android application  for handsets with high density and large screen size? I don't want it to be available for tablets as i'm planning to release a different apk for tablet.

I've read google's documentation here :[Declaring an App is Only for Handsets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

and added this in my manifest

```
<compatible-screens>

<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />

</compatible-screens>
```

I wonder if devices like Note 2 , xperia z and upcoming S4 and many other phones which are 
5.0 inches and more come under android:screenSize="normal" or android:screenSize="large"

and if I include android:screenSize="large" then  wouldn't it allow 7 inch tablets?

Comment: how did you solve it? android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" does not compile for me (Gradle: String types not allowed (at 'screenDensity' with value 'xxhdpi'). And with support screen it cannot be restricted to density as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

This article might help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Xperia Z and other devices come in large screen size. Also the screen density on these devices  is xxhdpi. I would recommend keeping support for only xlarge devices if you only plan to target tablets with this version of app.

you should use [support screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) tag rather than [compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) as recommended by the Android developer website.